# Copying a file and then printing the absolute path to its final destination

Tags: python

Ive been working on a piece of code to help me organize files. After much digging around and STACK's really good block of asking questions i was able to learn some stuff (by force).

```
def chkdir(d):
    pathsrc = os.path.abspath(d) #absolute path to each file
    fileparts = d.split('_')
    fileparts[2] = fileparts[2].replace('.mov', '')
    clipPath = os.path.join(postvispath, fileparts[0],fileparts[1], fileparts[2])

    if os.path.exists(clipPath): 
        print 'True: Path Exists, Ignoring'
        skiplist.append("%s"%tdy+" "+pathsrc)

    else:
        print 'False: Creating Path'
        transferlist.append("%s"%tdy+" "+pathsrc)

        try:
            os.makedirs(clipPath)
            shutil.copyfile(pathsrc, '%s/%s' %(clipPath, pathsrc.split('/')[-1]))
            print 
        except OSError as exc:
            if exc.errno == errno.EEXIST and os.path.isdir(path):
                pass
            else:
```

I want to know how append the absolute path of the destination these files are being copied to not the source as i have it setup now :) also as im learning if there is any mistakes in my code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and the wonderfully frustrating art of computer programming! I suggest you start by describing the steps to solve your problem in words. Once you have a very detailed step-by-step description, then you can start to translate it into python code. If you need to learn the basics of python syntax, you should check out the official tutorial at python.org.

Comment: but i have outlined steps above ? in a specific order even ?

Comment: okay, now take those steps and translate them into Python. If you have trouble with any of the steps, feel free to write a specific question. Be sure to read [ask] and [mcve] for some tips about how to write a good question.

Comment: actually i was struggling with that too :(, but didnt know how to phrase it. True story admit not the best description for my problem, agreed

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This code should solve your problem:

```
import os
import shutil

#lets say that the extension is mp4 but you can change it to the correct one
file_name = 'RRR_0010_V001.mp4'
file_name_parts = file_name.split('_')
#remove the extension for the last folder in the dir
file_name_parts[2] = file_name_parts[2].replace('.mp4', '')
directory = os.path.join(file_name_parts[0],file_name_parts[1],file_name_parts[2])
try:
    os.makedirs(directory)
except FileExistsError:
    with open('errors.log', 'a') as log:
        log.write('Error: File already exists.')

shutil.copy(file_name,directory)
```

This should make a directory based on your file name and copy the original file in there. But this works by default in the home dir, like C:\ in Windows and `/` in Linux. But I assume you already know how to change the dir to your preferred folder. But if you have any doubts, feel free to comment.

Edit:
For all the files in the cwd, the code is mostly the same.

```
import os
import shutil

#lets say that the extension is mp4 but you can change it to the correct one
def make_dir_with_file(file_name):
    file_name_parts = file_name.split('_')
    #remove the extension for the last folder in the dir
    file_name_parts[2] = file_name_parts[2].replace('.mp4', '')
    directory = os.path.join(file_name_parts[0],file_name_parts[1],file_name_parts[2])
    try:
        os.makedirs(directory)
    except FileExistsError:
        with open('errors.log', 'a') as log:
            log.write('Error: File already exists.')
    shutil.copy(file_name,directory)

for file in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    make_dir_with_file(file)
```

Comment: got a few errors

Comment: NameError: global name 'FileExistsError' is not defined

Comment: for file in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected unindent

Comment: ???, It works fine on mine. How about running the file from cmd/terminal: `python3 file.py`

Comment: yeah ill just have a look at that

Comment: it worked but still getting that error in terminal

Comment: what error are you still getting?